# SQL Management Studio Settings (Silent Install)

Tags: sql, settings, ssms, silent-installer

I've got some problems with the configuration of the sql management studio. 
The installation is no problem.

The problems apperead during the Configuration, i need to configure (in options):

- Tab Text (Text Editor -> Editor Tab and Status Bar)
- Results to Grid (Query Results -> SQL Server)

Where are this settings stored? 
How can I install them silent?

Answer (score 1):

found the solution, it's here documented.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/sqlgetstarted/thread/42cd7ff7-60c2-476f-b9ae-580518e845eb